# Undefined: syscall.Mmap on Windows 10

Tags: go, winapi, system-calls

I have this function in my Go project and I am getting the error as:

> undefined syscall.Mmap

```
func memMap(fd uintptr, base int64) (mem []uint32, mem8 []byte, err error) {
    mem8, err = syscall.Mmap(
        int(fd),
        base,
        memLength,
        syscall.PROT_READ|syscall.PROT_WRITE,
        syscall.MAP_SHARED,
    )
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    // Convert mapped byte memory to unsafe []uint32 pointer, adjust length as needed
    header := *(*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&mem8))
    header.Len /= (32 / 8) // (32 bit = 4 bytes)
    header.Cap /= (32 / 8)
    mem = *(*[]uint32)(unsafe.Pointer(&header))
    return
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### The problem

Windows does not have the `mmap(2)` syscall—[it's POSIX-specific](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html) (just in case: [what "POSIX" is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)).

Windows has [`MapViewOfFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761) and friends.

### Solutions

There are two approaches, I reckon:

- Use a "wrapper" package such as
  [`golang.org/x/exp/mmap`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/exp/mmap)
  which tries to provide a generic memory-mapping API which
  is cross-platform (that is, on POSIX platforms it will use
  `mmap(2)` and on Windows is will use Windows-specific API).
- Use the appropriate Win32 API functions directly instead of
  `syscall.Mmap`.

  Should you take this route, the
  [golang.org/x/sys/windows](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows) package has
  the relevant functions readily available.

A third approach is to have your own custom implementation
working with memory-mapped data which calls either
`syscall.Mmap` and friends of Windows-specific API.
Such implementation should supposedly involve using
so-called [build constraints](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints)
to conditionally compile a particular target platform-specific
implementation—just like `golang.org/x/exp/mmap` does.